# Java : performance of the instance without variable

Tags: java, performance

I had a class like this :

```
class Test
{
    public static test getInstance()
    {
        return new test()
    }

    public void firstMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
    public void secondMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
    public void thirdMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

in the another class if we calling `Test.getInstance().methodName()` several times with different method, what happening?
Which one will be **faster and using low memory** in following codes?

```
Test.getInstance().firstMethod()
Test.getInstance().secondMethod()
Test.getInstance().thirdMethod()
```

or

```
Test test = Test.getInstance();
test.firstMethod();
test.secondMethod();
test.thirdMethod();
```

Comment: @GáborBakos prove it

Comment: I don't think it will be any - It should be the same - the reason is that compiler optimises it anyway. at the end of the day, everything is in the heap space for Java and garbage collection chucks things out which you don't use up. The only thing that looks different in the first instance is the reference count for Test.getInstance().firstMethod()...etc. and just one `test` object. I think someone will surely put it in his/her answer to explain.

Comment: I think the second one's faster because the first one creates a new instance for each method call, right? Unless it gets optimized.

Comment: When you have a `getInstance()` method, it usually implies that you use the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which means only the first call will create a `new Test` and all subsequent calls return that one instance. When you have a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which is supposed to return a new instance whenever it is called, call it `create()` or `makeTest()`. Also, when the methods of your class don't use any variables, you should make them `static` and call them statically with `Test.methodName`.

Comment: But it's does not saving on anywhere ,how you can say second method is using low memory?

Comment: See my comment below, @Chris.  All objects are at least an instance of `Object`, which does have to allocate memory.  That does take time.

Comment: Created objects exist until they are garbage collected at JVMs whim. If they are created they do take up memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
Test.getInstance().firstMethod()
Test.getInstance().secondMethod()
Test.getInstance().thirdMethod()
```

This will create *three* different instances of the `Test` class and call a method on each.

```
Test test = Test.getInstance();
test.firstMethod();
test.secondMethod();
test.thirdMethod();
```

Will create only one instance and invoke the three methods on that instance.

So it's a completely different behavior to begin with. Obviously, since the first creates three objects, then it should take more heap space.

If you're intending to implement a singleton class, however, both are equivalent.

Comment: And since every object is an `Object`, the JIT might not be able to completely optimize the calls to `new` away.  So memory has to be allocated (takes a bit of time) and then garbage collected too (takes longer, but happens over time).

Comment: You did not answered to my question,i just want to know,witch one using low memory and faster than another?

Comment: @Chris The first code creates three objects while the second creates only one. I think it should be obvious from here.

Comment: in the first example the objects where are stored?

Comment: They may not be stored in variables, but they take up memory until they are garbage collected. The same can be said about the second code.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `getInstance` the system has to allocate heap storage for a `Test` object and initialize it.

Furthermore, somewhere down the line the system will have to garbage-collect all those extra `Test` objects.  With a copying collector the overhead per object is minimal, but there is some -- if for no other reason than you're causing GC to occur more often.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test 
{
    public static Test getInstance() 
    {
        return new Test();
    }

    public void firstMethod() 
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void secondMethod() 
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void thirdMethod() 
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class Blah 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Test t = new Test();
        for (; i < 100000; i++) 
        {
            t.firstMethod();
        }
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(stop - start);
        i = 0;
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (; i < 100000; i++) 
        {
            Test.getInstance().firstMethod();
        }
        stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(stop - start);

    }
}
```

output:

```
~3486938
~4894574
```

Creating single instance with new Test() proved to be consistently faster by about 30%.

Memory calculations are harder due to disability to do it in one run. However if we run only the first loop (changing what's inside) and use:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
```

just before printing. In two separate runs we can determine the difference: `~671200` or `~1342472` (seemed to change between runs rather randomly with no clear influence on runtime) for `new Test()` and `~2389288` (no big differences this time) for `getInstance()` in 100000 iterations. Again clear victory to single instance